# AWS | 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm doing a ASP.NET project currently, and I want to upload up in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. So I have all the prerequisite downloaded, installed and setup already, I used Visual Studio 2017 to publish my solution to AWS. There were no errors while uploading, however, when I click on my website link `xxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com`, it showed me `403` error.

There were no errors while creating env nor uploading the project onto AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the url for example, if your url is xxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com try to add the extension of your index file that you uploaded in your ZIP file.

Example:

xxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/index.html

Hope it helps